# Import mayavi in Spyder

Tags: spyder, mayavi

I get the following error in the Spyder console when trying to import mayavi in .py file:

ImportError: No module named mayavi

I tried to implement the method outlined in this post: [Mayavi doesn't run from within Spyder: complains about "ValueError: API 'QString' ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12442938/mayavi-doesnt-run-from-within-spyder-complains-about-valueerror-api-qstring)

However:

1) I don't get the same error as in that example

2) I can't change Qt4 to wx, the option is locked

I'd think I don't need to separately install mayavi since Spyder is using the ETS toolkit, or do I?

I am using Spyder 2.3.2 and Python 2.7.8. I tried both on a Mac and Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to provide some more information, but you may find this question helpful:
[importing module in Spyder error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693997/importing-module-in-spyder-error?rq=1)

What kind of behavior do you get in a ipython console at a terminal?

If you can get the example given in the question you referenced working in ipython, then it's probably just a setting within spyder as in the ref above.